# Passing inequalities to re-assign variables in an array/list

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a list or array of values `X` and I use the code:

```
X[X>=1]=1
```

I have a clean re-assignment of all values in `X` greater than or equal to `1` set equal to `1`.

If I try the following:

```
X[X>0 and X<1] = 0.5
```

It ignores both and does nothing. Is there a way to have two inequalities enforced in a single line using this approach?

Comment: Is `X` a numpy array?

Comment: You should use `X[(X>0) & (X<1)] = 0.5`. The code you show should actually raise an error. So I'm curious about the "ignores both" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
X[(X>0) & (X<1)] = 0.5
```

Comment: It does indeed! What is the difference between "and" and "&" ? Thank you.

Comment: @AmusingAutomatons `x and y` returns [`x if not x else y`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not). So the code you show in OP should've actually raised an error. `&` is just bitwise and.

Comment: '&' is the syntax for "and" in Pandas. I appreciate if you rate my answer if it was useful for you

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work : `X = [0.5 for i in X if (i>0) & (i<1)]`
edit : both `&` and `and` work on this.